# How to add whatsapp like top tab using react navigation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to make whatsapp clone using react native. But while adding camera screen I am not sure how to hide header and tab label in that specific screen.

so far this is my code
this is the code repo
https://github.com/adityakmr7/whatsapp-react-native

If anyone has any idea about this please help us fix this. Thank you

```
const MaterialTopTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="chats"
      tabBarOptions={{
        indicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
        },
        tabStyle: {
          justifyContent: "flex-start",
          alignItems: "flex-start",
        },
        activeTintColor: LIGHT_COLOR,
        labelStyle: { fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold" },
        style: { backgroundColor: PRIMARY },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="camera"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: () => (
            <View>
              <Icon name="camera" size={26} color={PRIMARY_DARK} />
            </View>
          ),
        }}
        component={CameraScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="chats" component={Chats} />
      <Tab.Screen name="status" component={Status} />
      <Tab.Screen name="calls" component={Calls} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const Main = ({}: MainProps) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor={PRIMARY_DARK} />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
              title: "WhatsApp",
              headerTintColor: LIGHT_COLOR,
              headerStyle: {
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: PRIMARY,
              },
              headerRight: () => {
                return (
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => console.log("Search")}
                      style={{ marginHorizontal: 15 }}
                    >
                      <Icon name="search" size={26} color={LIGHT_COLOR} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => console.log("menu Clicked")}
                      style={{ marginHorizontal: 5 }}
                    >
                      <Icon
                        name="more-vertical"
                        size={26}
                        color={LIGHT_COLOR}
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                );
              },
            })}
            name="home"
            component={MaterialTopTab}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: You might not need to focus on hiding things if you want to emulate Whatsapp for Android. I remember using [this library for taking pictures](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#image) and having it open the camera in a new intent on button click. You could keep the structure the same and call the `openCamera` function inside a `useEffect` hook for example. Then you don't need to hide anything.

Comment: I am use `expo-camera` I tried putting my openCamera function inside `useEffect` inside camera screen. But problem is still there it shows header there and i couldn't find any way to remove it in camera screen yet.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing to you. Not implement yet, but hope to be helpful:
React Navigation uses Reavt-native-gesture-handler and the Navigator has a prop:

```
gestureHandlerProps={{
    onGestureEvent: (e) => {
          console.log('i');
        },
        onHandlerStateChange: (e) => {
          
        }
            
     }}
```

onGestureEvent will call 100 times from the old screen to new screen. I think you can add some animation here. I'm Actually doing this~

Answer (score 0):

```
...
options={{
  tabBarIcon: () => (
    <View>
      <Icon name="camera" size={26} color={PRIMARY_DARK} />
    </View>
  ),
  tabBarLabel: () => null,
}}
...
```

You should change tabBarLabel to null to make your header gone and add tabBarIcon to display in the tab bar with icon.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no direct way in the library to implement this feature, You can use something like,

```js
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: '#03894E', width: '100%', height: 45, marginRight: 15, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
                onPress={() => {
                    //Do something here
                }}
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name='camera' size={25} color={'#fff'}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Tab.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{
                        tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 13, color: '#fff', fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold', width: "100%", textAlign: 'flex-start', },
                        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#03894E', height: 45, width: "100%", alignSelf: 'flex-end', },
                        tabBarContentContainerStyle: { flex: 1 },
                        tabBarIndicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff', height: 3, borderRadius: 100 },
                    }}>
                    <Tab.Screen name="chats" component={Chats} />
                    <Tab.Screen name="status" component={Status} />
                    <Tab.Screen name="calls" component={Calls} />
                </Tab.Navigator>
            </View>
```

But this is just an alternative. You cannot swipe to the camera tab, you need to click on the icon and manually show the content or navigate to that required page.

Note: Add the required navigation or any other functionality to the onPress event of the TouchableOpacity to achieve the desired output.